# Xamarin, namespaces without "using" keyword

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to do something like

```
public class MyActivity : Android.Support.V4.FragmentActivity { ....
```

But `Support.V4....` doesn't show in the autofill, and if I write it manually it just give me the `unknown resolve error`

Do I have to set up something before trying to do that?

PS: if I use `using Android.Support.V4.App;` it works, but I need NOT to use `using` keyword

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the problem was that my app namespace was `MyApp.Android` so whenever I typed `Android` it was referring to my app, not the library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a reference to `Mono.Android.Support.v4` in your Android solution, then you can extend the class without importing the library with a using statement:

`public class MyActivity: Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity { ...`

Comment: I already have `Mono.Android.Support.v4` in References in my Android Project

Comment: Make sure your extension has `App` after `V4` - your example doesn't seem to contain it.  Should be `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that your application uses a fragment of the namespace you are targetting, you might have to use the global:: scope.

Example:

```
// your code
namespace MyApp.Android {

// then later, try to use the "real" android namespace:
Android.Support.V4 //whoops -- .net tries to use your MyApp.Android namespace
// so instead do this:
global::Android.Support.V4 //...
```

Here's a better description of what's going on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx

**Edit**

In addition to the global:: identifier, you can can also use an extern alias

Example:

```
extern alias Android;
namespace MyApp.Android
{
  class Demo: Android::Android.Support.V4...
{
```